# can not create project for opendaylight With Maven Archetype

Tags: maven, sdn, opendaylight

I want create project for opendaylight with Maven Archetype and import into eclipse but when type this code for create project

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.OpenDaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=OpenDaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeRepository=https://nexus.OpenDaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.OpenDaylight.org/content/repositories/public/archetype-catalog.xml
```

this will make the error

```
 Generating project in Interactive mode
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 3.004 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-30T19:47:52+04:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/138M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-   
     plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: archetypeCatalog 'https://   
     nexus.OpenDaylight.org/content/repositories/public/archetype-catalog.xml' is not  
    supported anymore. Please read the plugin documentation for details. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
     [ERROR] 
     [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the    
     following articles: 
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/  
     MojoFailureException
```

how to can resolved this problem ?or create new project?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This option is displayed when you check **create simple project**

I always prefer to start building the ODL application through Eclipse.

Select "`Create Maven Project`" and click next which will ask you to fill various details. Fill the details as follows:

**Artifacts:**

- Group ID: org.opendaylight.yourprojectname
- Artifact ID: yourprojectname
- Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
- packaging: pom

**Parent**

- Group ID: **org.opendaylight.odlparent**
- Artifact ID: **bundle-parent**
- Version: **1.8.1-Carbon** (*or any other stable version*)

> wait for eclipse to download all related components.

PS: **I am assuming you have your settings.xml file updated. If Not use this [settings.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendaylight/odlparent/master/settings.xml) to update your existing settings.xml accordingly**

And now you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for how to use Maven archetype is here: http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html

It was more or less broken in previous releases, and has recently been fixed on the master branch for the future Fluorine release; more details here: https://jira.opendaylight.org/browse/DOCS-60 and